# Python Beautiful Soup Most Efficient Way to Find Tags

Tags: python, xml, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I am parsing many large XML files using python and BeautifulSoup. I often run into the following task:

```
<Section1>
    <Report>
        <Matrix>...</Matrix>
        <Matrix>...</Matrix>
        <Matrix>...</Matrix>
        <Matrix>...</Matrix>
    </Report>
</Section1>
```

I am trying to gather and iterate through all of the matrices. I use code like the following:

```
res = urlopen(url)
html = res.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')
matrices = soup.find("Section1").find_all("Matrix")
#Then I handle each matrix
```

Why can't I use a selector like this?

```
matrices = soup.find("Section1 Matrix")
```

Is there a faster way to do this? Sometimes I am accessing nodes nested much further in the XML and I need to make sure that they are descendants, but not necessarily direct children of several other nodes. The example a provided is a simplification. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use lxml?
it will boost a lot of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup ["supports CSS selectors"](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) you need to pass your selector to the `.select` method

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

In [2]: soup = BS("""<Section1>
   ...:     <Report>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:     </Report>
   ...: </Section1>""", "xml")

In [3]: soup.select("Section1 Matrix")
Out[3]: 
[<Matrix>...</Matrix>,
 <Matrix>...</Matrix>,
 <Matrix>...</Matrix>,
 <Matrix>...</Matrix>]
```

---

If what you want is to get all `Matrix` nodes in your document; you can use 
the [**`CSSSelector`**](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html#the-cssselector-class) class from [**`lxml.cssselect`**](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html)<sup>1</sup>.

```
In [3]: from lxml.etree import fromstring

In [4]: xml_doc = '''<Section1>
   ...:     <Report>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:         <Matrix>...</Matrix>
   ...:     </Report>
   ...: </Section1>'''

In [5]: tree = fromstring(xml_doc)

In [6]: matrix = [el for el in sel(tree)]

In [7]: matrix
Out[7]: 
[<Element Matrix at 0x7f84b5b8f388>,
 <Element Matrix at 0x7f84b5b8fc48>,
 <Element Matrix at 0x7f84b5b8fd88>,
 <Element Matrix at 0x7f84b5b8fdc8>]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You  need to install cssselect if it was not already installed with pip: `pip install cssselect`